# Keep using IE11 functionality after expiry

Tags: vbscript, internet-explorer-11, end-of-life

I am trying to understand how to keep using a legacy intranet "web application" based on *VBScript* (a scripting language supported by IE11, a still supported product, at the moment of writing).

I am afraid that at some point, after Windows update and the planned IE11 EoL, that intranet application will not be usable any more, so I am looking for a configuration to keep using IE11 or a migration option to a newer product. What matters to me is that it should support the legacy infrastructure.

Comment: Dear downvoter, pleas can you specify what's wrong with that question? so that i could improve my question quality next time. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This site generally much prefers questions that show research effort at least to the level of linking and reading the relevant vendor documentation (here: *KB article*) about the change you are asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer will be [disabled](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/05/19/the-future-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-is-in-microsoft-edge/) in Windows on June 15 2022, so you technically will not be able to start Internet Explorer after this date in Windows 10 20H2+ (starting iexplore.exe will open Edge instead).

However, if your web app requires Internet Explorer, then you can configure IE mode in Edge:
Take a look at:
[What is IE Mode?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/edge-ie-mode) and
[Getting started guide](https://aka.ms/IEModeGuide)

Basically, if it works in IE today, it will work in Edge with IE Mode. This is not an emulation, it is the actual IE11 engine.

Comment: thanks for the answer, seems that VBScript are still supported, from what I am reading. I will test that. Did you know if there are any issue in that mode (regarding compatibility)?

Comment: @Skary I don't expect any compatibility issue with IE mode in Microsoft Edge since they basically start IE in the background (of course, no one here can ever test everything we were able to do in IE to guarantee this). [Microsoft takes responsibility for compatibility](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-app-assure-blog/dual-engine-advantage-legacy-sites-and-microsoft-edge/ba-p/2114756) and you can get help from Microsoft if something is not working

Comment: thanks a lot for all the information and support, i'll start testing the solution you have highlited in the next few days.